# using spring-boot-maven-plugin with exec classifier, but can't run the app from IDE anymore

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am working on Spring Boot 1.5.9 application, and I am generating a jar that contains a Spring Boot application, but that can also be imported as part of another project.

Therefore, I am using below config to generate 2 jars : the exec, and the regular lib ones.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, now that I have this, I am not able to run the application from my IDE (Intellij) anymore, as it's not finding the application.yml.

I am sure there's a trick, but I can't find anything.. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Maven profiles :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>makeRelease</id>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I make the release, I am calling this profile (maven with argument -P makeRelease) so that it generates the 2 jars.

The rest of the time, the regular behavior applies.